# Two players multiply a number until it reaches 1000

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, game-theory

Two players start with $1$ and take turns multiplying it by $2$ or $3$ or $4$ ... or $9$. The first player to make the number $\ge 1000$ wins. Who has a winning strategy?

My attempt: obviously $112$ is a losing position since $112*9=1008$. Then 
it's a winning position for all numbers between $56$ to $111$. Then the first player can choose to multiply by $5$ on the first turn, then on his second turn he can always multiply a number so it's between $56$ and $111$. Therefore the first player has a winning strategy.

Is this solution correct. Is there another way of doing it? Also, in general, who has a winning strategy if the first player to make the number $\ge n$ wins?

Comment: Do you think "generalization" is a good tag?

Comment: I think the usual terminology is to call $112$ a _winning_ position (i.e. it is winning for the player to move).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a good strategy and demonstration that it works.  $4$ and $6$ also work.

You might compare with the game where you add instead of multiply and are allowed to add $1,2,3,4$ at each turn and the first to reach some total, say $27$ wins.  A player can always guarantee that two successive turns add to $5$, so the first player wins by taking $2$, then hitting $7,12,17,22,27$.

In your game a player can guarantee that two turns multiply by at least $18$ but one turn cannot multiply by more than $9$.  Your $56$ comes from $\lceil \frac {1000}{18}\rceil$ and $111$ from $\lfloor \frac {1000}9 \rfloor$.  This suggests that for target $T$ and $n$ pairs of turns before the end you should leave between $\lceil \frac T{18^n} \rceil$ and $\lfloor \frac T{18^{n-1}\cdot 9}\rfloor$  The worry is that you can't guarantee that two turns will multiply by exactly $18$.  If your opponent multiplies by $7$ you have to choose between $2$ and $3$, making the pair multiply by $14$ or $21$.  I believe you are OK because the range is a factor $2$.  In this example if multiplying by $3$ is too much, $2$ will be enough to stay in range.